# Where has the Additional Bounty button gone?

Tags: discussion, support

I want set additional bounty on [Regex Pattern to Match, Excluding when… / Except between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between) to reward the superb answer again.

I saw some other people do this and it seem classy.

Before I thought I seen "Additional Bounty" button for this, but now it's not showing.

Comment: I see the normal bounty button, is that not sufficient?

Comment: Hi Hans, I'm flattered you'd want to reward my answer again, but you really don't have to do that. The original bounty was already very large by the standard of regex questions, and I appreciated it. Maybe save the rep points you've earned, they can be useful for other things. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to offer [double the bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639) each time if repeating a bounty on the same question (until reaching the 500 max).

You previously [placed a bounty of 200](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3602383/hans-schindler?tab=bounties&sort=offered) on that question. Doubling is 400. You currently have 382 rep.

Comment: Not enough barbies mate.

Comment: Thank you explaining to @HansSchindler how to spend all his bonus points including the ones he hasn't earned yet. :) But that seems a bit extravagant, I'll comment on his question.